# How to edit a characters in a string, and remove characters that editing conditions apply to

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take in a number from a user, display the number as a range,and then replace instances of the number 3 with a string, instances of the number 2 with a string, and instances of the number 1 with a string. If the function detects a 3, I want it to replace it with the string, remove the instance of 3, and ignore the conditions for replacing 2 & 1. The same goes for when it sees a 2 (but not a 2).

I have the function taking in the number from the user, converting it to a string, and then displaying it as a range using a for loop.

In the for loop I use .includes to look for a '3.' When it sees one it is pushing the string "I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that" to the same list that displays the range.

I've tried an if/else if statement to have the loop ignore the conditions for 2 and 1 if it first sees a three, however it is applying all conditions to all instances of 3,2, or 1.

```
function numTranslate(inputNumber){
  var numList = [];
  var num = inputNumber

for (i = 0; i<= num; i++){

var numString = i.toString();

if (numString.includes('3')) {
  numList.push("I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that")
} 

else if (numString.includes('2')) {
  numList.push("boop!")
}
else if (numString.includes('1')) {
  numList.push("beep!")
}

  numList.push(i)
}
return numList;
}
```

What I'm getting

input: 9

Output: 0,beep!,1,boop!,2,I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

What I want:

input: 9

Output: 1,2, I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want to print 1 and 2 why do you have an if clause for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that output then remove the if clauses for 1 and 2. Your code is working fine except for those 2 if clauses. Also, start at 1 if you want to ignore 0.

Another thing, why in the world are you converting this to a string and then checking  if the string includes the char? These are numbers, do number operations on them. You are adding unnecessary overhead by converting them and checking against the conversion.

```js
function numTranslate(inputNumber){
  var numList = [];
  var num = inputNumber

for (i = 1; i<= num; i++){
    if(i === 3){
        numList.push("I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that");
    }else{
        numList.push(i);
    }
}
return numList;
}

console.log(numTranslate(9));
```

Comment: I don't think you can do .includes on numbers? I tried that and it wouldn't let me run the method

Comment: My point is however is why are you converting it to a string? You are literally just checking the value of i. So why convert it to a string? If you want a string in your end array just use .toString().

Comment: @JackCollins re-type int to string and compare string with number is awfull.

Comment: My point is what @daremachine is saying. There is no reason to retype to do comparations on that new value. Just do actual number checking.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks for that. I learned I didn't need to do .includes if I simply just did i===num

Comment: @JackCollins - keep in mind that `===` doesn't do type coercion. That means that if you compare `"3" === 3` it'll be false. For type coercion you can use `"3" == 3` - though typically you should never _have_ to.

Comment: @zfrisch, thanks for the tip. I changed the code to simply compare integers.

Comment: Great @JackCollins glad we were able to help :) If this helped solve your issue please mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way of doing it.

```js
function numTranslate(inputNumber){
 return Array.from(Array(inputNumber), function (value, index) {
 var i = index+1;
 if (i== 1 || i==2){
   return "beep!";
   }

 if (i== 3){
   return "I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that";
 }
 return i.toString()

});
}

console.log(numTranslate(9))
```